# Replace special chars in between only, not start and end of the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I need to replace special character '(apostrope) with \'(back slash apostrope) but this should be only in between the string except starting and ending characters of the string.
eg: `msg ='My Son's Daughter';`
There can be multiple apostropes in the string. I just want to replace apostropes in the string which are not starting and ending characters.

Please share me any ideas.

Comment: `msg = msg.replace(/'/g, "\'")`? - the starting and ending quotes are string delimiters...

Comment: colon is `:` You mean apostrophe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of `substr()` and regex:

```
var msg ="'My Son's Daughter'";

msg = msg.substr(0, 1) + msg.substr(1, msg.length-2).replace(/'/g, "\\'") + msg.substr(msg.length-1, 1);
```

Outputs:

```
'My Son\'s Daughter'
```

As shown, only the inner `'` are replaced, the first and last are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
msg = msg.replace(/(.)'(.)/g, "$1\\'$2");
```

The `.` at beginning and end will require any character before and after the `'`.

The `()` will catch that charachter defined in it (`.`) to a variable (`$1` and `$2`).

The `$1` and `$2` represent the catched character of both `()`.

The `\\` escapes/represents a literal `\`

The `/` at the start, just before the `g` defines this as a Regular Expression (regex)

The `g` is a modifier (global) that will indicate ALL occurrences.

The regex should NOT be put between quotes as if it was a string.

Comment: its output something like this `My Son\'s Daughter` and OP person want something like this `My Son\s Daughter`

Comment: @DevangRathod Nope... OP states **I need to replace special character '(colon) with \'(back slash colon)** . Disregard the colon/apostrophe mistake in OP, you end up with replace `'` with `\'`

Comment: @nl-x This is working only for the first apostrope. for the remaining it is not working, except starting and ending apostropes

Comment: ah, yes, forgot to add the `g`. I just put it back

Answer (score 0):

The [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function is what you're after. This should do the trick:

```
msg = msg.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

Comment: He does *not* want any first or last `'` to be slashed as well. Only characters in between. So this is not a solution.

Comment: In his example the first and last `'` characters are string delimiters. This code won't replace string delimiters.

Comment: I see what you are hinting at. He explicitly states **but this should be only in between the string except starting and ending characters of the string.** ... But him being someone who doesn't know an apostrophe from his colon (haha) , you are probably right.

Comment: I'm also slightly confused by `msg ='My Son's Daughter'`. How is that even valid syntax to begin with?

Comment: Maybe the string is `msg ='My Son's Daughter';` and the code is `var myString "msg ='My Son's Daughter';";` ... and the result should be `msg =\'My Son\'s Daughter';` ;)